# can I use my controller in laravel 8 to delet row that checked in view?

Tags: php, html, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <body>
        <button class="btn" onclick="deleteSelected()">delete</button>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="chkd()">
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Paragraph</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ss" value="{{ $categorie->id }}" onclick="deleteSelected()">
                        </td>
                        <th scope="row">{{ $categorie->id }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $categorie->Title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $categorie->Paragraph }}</td>
                        <form action={{ route('categorie.destroy', $categorie->id) }} method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <td>
                                <button id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" style="display: none">
                                    delete
                                </button>
                        </form>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning"> <a href={{ route('edit', $categorie->id) }}>edit</a> </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
 </body>
@endsection
```

that is my view , when I check one of my checkbox and press the button delete I want this row to be deleted or when I checked all I want to delete all row

Comment: Form elements go _inside_ the `<form>...</form>` (unless there's a `form` attribute). `<a href` inside a `<button>` doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

I think html **input** must inside the **form**. How about moving code like this:

```
    @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action={{ route('categorie.destroy', $categorie->id) }} method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ss" value="{{ $categorie->id }}" onclick="deleteSelected()">
                        <button id="deleteRow" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" style="display: none">
                            delete
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <th scope="row">{{ $categorie->id }}</th>
                <td>{{ $categorie->Title }}</td>
                <td>{{ $categorie->Paragraph }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-warning"> <a href={{ route('edit', $categorie->id) }}>edit</a> </button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    @endforeach
```

But, I don't know this is can fix your case or not. I can't see the whole code